# Unable to communicate between guest OS in VirtualBox in both

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, ping, kali-linux

I was wondering that can we connect guest os in virtual box via internal networking like physical machine networking.

So I created two guest OS having Kali in one vm and windows in another vm, and creates a dhcp server via `vboxmanage` command

the command i fired is enter code here

```
vboxmanage dhcpserver add --netname testnet --ip 10.0.0.1 --netmaask 255.255.255.0 --upperip 10.0.0.20 --lowerip 10.0.0.10 --enable
```

and assigned to vm via internal network and allowed the Promiscuous Mode to `Allow VMs`. Please also explain what is Promiscuous Mode.

Assigned static IP to Kali Linux is 10.0.0.20 and assigned static IP to windows is 10.0.0.10.

I was successful at one end only means able to ping Kali with windows but failed to ping Windows via Kali Linux

[Result of Ping from Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx47R.png)

[Result of Ping from Kali Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDIFH.jpg)

I also tried same by Windows 7 and Windows 8, successful in pinging Windows 8 but failed to ping Windows 7.

Also if static ip's not alloted, the guest os are not getting default gateway address, but only getting IP Address.

Any ideas how to enable both side communication.

Thanks in advance :):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and assigned to vm via internal network and allowed the Promiscuous
>   Mode to Allow VMs. Please also explain what is Promiscuous Mode.

Promiscuous mode allows the host to see all frames received on the NIC, regardless of whether or not they were destined to that host.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode

> I was successful at one end only means able to ping Kali with windows
>   but failed to ping Windows via Kali Linux

Windows Firewall is probably blocking ICMP.

> Also if static ip's not alloted, the guest os are not getting default
>   gateway address, but only getting IP Address.

I'm assuming that when you say "virtual box via internal networking" you're referring to the actual network type of "internal networking" as defined here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

If you note in your DHCP command, there's no actual default gateway definition. Further, that function wouldn't make sense in a "internal network" as VB describes it. As it's an isolated network, known only to the VM's sharing it, there's no way to route in and out of it.

If you'd like the VM's to be able to communicate with one another and access the internet/other hosts on your physical network, "NAT" or "Bridged" network types.

Comment: I also tested between two windows os. Windows 7 and Windows 8, and same goes for that.

Comment: Latest version of Virtual box shows Bridge Adapter instead of Bridge Networking.

Comment: - I still suspect Windows 7 has its firewall blocking ICMP. You can just fully disable it if this is just a lab. We know the Win7 VM can communicate in general since it could ping Kali.
- How did you make the VM's initially, via VirtualBox's GUI, or a command line similar to how you propped up DHCP?
- If they are in fact bridged (and importantly, through your primary network adapter), they should be receiving leases from your network's router (or whatever device is providing DHCP, I'm assuming this is a home network.)

Comment: I created them via GUI Interface. Well I solved it. Thanks for your answer